# JavaScript Array Filtering and Mapping Problem. How to do nesting filtering?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mapping, filtering

Suppose, I have an array.

```
const arr = [
      {
        category: 'Diner',
        item: [
          {name: 'Chicken Rice', price: 200},
          {name: 'Mutton Rice', price: 300},
        ],
      },
      {
        category: 'Breakfast',
        item: [
          {name: 'Tea Bisuit', price: 100},
          {name: 'Bread Butter', price: 300},
          {name: 'Green Tea', price: 80},
        ],
      },
    ];
```

How can I **filter** the array according to the item name?
For example, how can I filter the array with the item name **Green Tea**?

Output must be like this:

```
arr = [
        {
          category: 'Breakfast',
          item: [
            {name: 'Green Tea', price: 80},
          ],
       },
     ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `map` through `arr`, with each element, filter `item` to which match the term

After that, `filter` the `arr` again to reject the elements whose `item` is empty

```js
const arr = [ { category: "Diner", item: [ { name: "Chicken Rice", price: 200 }, { name: "Mutton Rice", price: 300 }, ], }, { category: "Breakfast", item: [ { name: "Tea Bisuit", price: 100 }, { name: "Bread Butter", price: 300 }, { name: "Green Tea", price: 80 }, ], }, ]

const term = "Green Tea"

const res = arr
  .map((categoryAndItems) => ({
    category: categoryAndItems.category,
    item: categoryAndItems.item.filter((item) => item.name === term),
  }))
  .filter((categoryAndItems) => categoryAndItems.item.length > 0)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Minor suggestion, do filter first and then map. You do not need to transform objects that will be filtered out

Comment: @Rajesh sure, thanks. could filter in one go, I just want to clarify steps 